# How I can get firebase auth error and console log message and code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js

I want to console log firebase auth when error appear, but nothing is in the console log, doesn't even step in into catch block. I'm not sure why this is happening and how to get error to check for code and message to be able to do something with this. I can only see error appear like shown in the picture but nothing in the console.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta7tr.png)

Here is a code:

```
if(remember){
        setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
    } 
    setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
    .then(() => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    })
    .catch((err:any) => {
      console.log(err.message + "error");
      switch (err.code) {
        case "auth/Invalid-email":
        case "auth/user-disabled":
        case "auth/user-not-found":
          setError(err.message);
          break;
        case "auth/wrong-password":
          setError(err.message)
          break;
        default:
      }
    });
  };
```

I will appreciate any advice. Thank you a lot. Have a good day all :))

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding much the logic behind the code block but you've attached the catch to `setPersistence` not to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

Here is a correction which will output you the errors from `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, also I've added `FirebaseError` for error type

```
import { FirebaseError } from "firebase/app";

if(remember){
    setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
} 
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
.then(() => {
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).catch((err:FirebaseError ) => {
  console.log(err.message + "error");
  switch (err.code) {
    case "auth/Invalid-email":
    case "auth/user-disabled":
    case "auth/user-not-found":
      setError(err.message);
      break;
    case "auth/wrong-password":
      setError(err.message)
      break;
    default:
   }
 });
});
```